# Can Force.com Sites enforce https without a certificate from it’s branded custom domain?

Tags: force.com-sites, ssl, custom-domain, tls

I have a situation where the CNAME record on a domain will be updated to look up to a force.com site. Currently the “Enforce HTTPS” checkbox on our force.com sites config is checked and we would like to keep it that way. However, our domain currently does not have a certificate.

Would it be possible to move forward with repointing our domain to force.com without a certificate? If we do need a certificate, would it need to be signed? What type of issues could the sites end users experience if there was no certificate, signed or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to move forward without your domain having certificate .You can use platform provided  certificate and get it CA signed .

> Create a Certificate Authority (CA) Signed Certificate from your org

1. Click Setup.
2. Under "Administer," click Security Controls | then click Certificate and Key Management.
3. Click Create CA-Signed Certificate.
4. Click Download Certificate Signing Request.
     -After the certificate downloads, you'll need to send it to a CA of your choice.

The last step is to upload the certificate after it is CA signed .This article describes everything in [depth](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205653&language=en_US)